# remove from table 2 if not in table 1, based on 2 fields

Tags: php, mysql

They both have fileId and userId fields

table 1: 
fileId userId

table 2: 
fileId userId

I would like to remove all rows from table 2 if they are not in table 1, based on their fileId and userId.. not just one field but on both...

Kind regards,
J

Comment: and what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
delete from table2 
where fileid not in (select fileid from table1)
and userId not in (select userId from table1)
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY ( assume `id` is primary key of both table )

```
DELETE FROM table2
WHERE id NOT IN ( 
        SELECT 'id' FROM table1 t1 
        INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON ( t1.field=t2.filed AND t1.userid = t2.userid)
        )
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and I would imagine it would be faster than the accepted answer, however I haven't got a id primary key... I will test it though.. regards J

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM table2 WHERE userId NOT IN (SELECT userId from table1) AND 
                         fileId NOT IN (SELECT fileId from table1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but juergen beat you by 2 mins!.. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this approach. tested working.

```
CREATE table table1(field varchar(10),userid varchar(20));
CREATE table table2(field varchar(10),userid varchar(20));

insert into table1 values('10','vish');
insert into table1 values('11','atul');
insert into table1 values('12','nish');

insert into table2 values('10','vish');
insert into table2 values('11','atul');
insert into table2 values('13','paul');
insert into table2 values('14','ganesh');

DELETE from table2
WHERE NOT exists 
(select field+userid from table1 t1 where t1.field+userid = table2.field+userid);

SELECT * FROM table2;
```